# Change w32tm source to external server

Tags: windows, domain-controller, ntp

We have an on-premises NTP server named NTPserver and adjust the w32tm source to time.windows.com.

There is a domain controller server that the w32tm source is Local CMOS clock.

I want to change the source of the domain controller server from Local CMOS clock to NTPserver.

Answer (score 2):

You configure the DC's time source the same way you configure the member server's time source. Run these commands from an administrator command prompt on the DC:

```
w32tm.exe /config /syncfromflags:manual /manualpeerlist:<NTP server IP or FQDN>,0x8 /reliable:yes /update
```

and then

```
net stop w32time && net start w32time
```

That being said, you could easily save yourself some complexity and have the DC sync against time.windows.com directly instead of having a **separate**, dedicated time server on your network.

To check the NTP configuration on the DC, use

```
w32tm /query /configuration
```

To do a manual time sync on the DC instead of waiting for the automatic sync, use

```
w32tm /resync /nowait
```

The w32tm.exe program has a bunch of other options to manipulate the w32time service.

Tip: any host that can sync time with NTP or SNTP can use the Windows DC as time source.

If you sync time against an external NTP server, remember to open port 123 UDP in the public facing firewall.